# Persisting flash when a form is submitted multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Background: I have essentially a multiple choice quiz. When a user submits a form, `update` scores their answer, chooses a new question, puts a message in the flash, and redirects back to the `show` action. `show` displays the message and the new question.

The immediate problem is that if they submit the form twice, `update` gets called twice. The first time scores their answer for the question they were given. The second time scores their answer for the question that was just now selected, which they haven't seen yet. So then they get redirected with a message saying something like "wrong! The answer is Spain, not Italy" When they had been choosing between Hydrogen and Helium.

So my first solution to this is to include a question_id field in the submitted form. If the submitted id isn't the id of the question that was asked, just ignore this request. This works for keeping track, but the message that was stored in the flash is lost.

So I've tried adding `flash.keep` if the ids don't match. My thinking is that one `update` will set the flash, and then the next request received will be the second `update`. But the flash is still getting lost. It seems that the second `update` doesn't start with a flash at all, which confuses me.

So my questions are: is there a better way to handle this problem? And if not, why is the flash disappearing?

`update` looks something like this (some lines omitted):

```
def update
  game = current_user.credence_game
  question = game.current_question

  if params[:question_id].to_i == question.id
    given_answer = params[:answer_index].to_i
    credence = params[:credence].to_i
    correct, score = question.score_answer(given_answer, credence)

    game.score += score
    game.new_question
    game.save

    flash[:correct] = correct
    flash[:score] = score
    flash[:message] = question.answer_message(given_answer)
  else
    flash.keep
  end

  redirect_to action: 'show'
end
```

If I add a `p flash` line just before `redirect_to`, the server spits out this:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f2a8431b4a0 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:correct=>false, :score=>-32, :message=>"Incorrect. The right answer is White River (Arkansas) (1102km) versus Yellowstone River (1080km)."}, @now=nil>


Started PUT "/credence" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 15:20:16 +0100
  Processing by CredenceController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EiqXDoFy77nmdKOE4YkHOeEFg4DvB5zdgFi98ynNCx0=", "question_id"=>"52", "credence"=>"60", "answer_index"=>"1", "commit"=>"60%"}
<Model stuff>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/credence
Completed 302 Found in 667ms
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x000000059864f8 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=nil>


Started PUT "/credence" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 15:20:18 +0100
  Processing by CredenceController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EiqXDoFy77nmdKOE4YkHOeEFg4DvB5zdgFi98ynNCx0=", "question_id"=>"52", "credence"=>"70", "answer_index"=>"1", "commit"=>"70%"}
<Model stuff, just loading the game and the question>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/credence
Completed 302 Found in 421ms


Started GET "/credence" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 15:20:19 +0100
  Processing by CredenceController#show as HTML
<Model stuff>
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (400.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 963ms (Views: 776.4ms | ActiveRecord: 27.7ms)

<GET requests for CSS, images, etc.>
```

So it does seem like the first request after the flash is set, is the one where I'm calling `flash.keep`, but it still doesn't have the flash.

**Edit**: I'm realising the problem is likely that I'm using CookieStore. The first request doesn't get a chance to set cookies before the second request is sent. Using the session instead of flash would have the same issue.

A simple solution here, that I don't much like, would be to simply disable the forms with javascript onsubmit. A more complicated one would be: when the question ids don't match, look up the answer that the user gave for the submitted question id, and set the flash appropriately without changing the score.

Any alternatives?

Comment: use session instead of flash

Comment: That might work, sure. But I think I'm using the flash for its intended purpose, and using the session instead would basically be me reimplementing the flash because I can't figure out how it works. That seems like a bad idea, in general.

Comment: how hard would it be to regenerate the original flash message? (ie, instead of retrieving it, just recreate it again)

Comment: That wouldn't be too awful in this case. Part of me feels like, surely this is a problem that comes up every time you have a form that can't be submitted multiple times? So it feels like there should be a general solution to this, although I have no idea what it would look like. But if there isn't, that's probably what I'll have to do.